# How to fit Tkinter listbox to contents

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I'm adding strings to a listbox using the code below. When I run the code and the window opens, the longer strings get clipped as the window is not large enough (see screenshot). I have tried making the window resizeable and adding scroll bars but I was wondering if there was a way to automatically size it to fit the content.

```py
master = tk.Tk()
listbox = tk.Listbox(master, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)

games = ["Garry's Mod", "Mount and Blade: Warband", "Tekkit"]
for game in sorted(games):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, game)

button = tk.Button(master, text="Execute", command=execute)

listbox.pack()
button.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

[image: example of clipped listbox]

Comment: Have you tried scaling the width (in pixels) based on the list item which has the maximum number of characters? (This may not work since characters != number of pixels but it may get you to think of a better solution.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Resetting the listbox width worked for me. I used the Oblivion's answer and noticed that the width is always zero.

```
listbox = tk.Listbox(master, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
listbox.config(width=0)
```

I also recommend to reset the root window geometry after reloading a content of the list. Otherwise if user manually extends a window the window would stop accommodate size of its content.

```
root.winfo_toplevel().wm_geometry("")
```

Answer (score 5):

just give width and height 0 as below

```
listbox.config(width=0,height=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is sooo much better than all the other ones.

Comment: NOTE: if your list is large than your screen it will truncate the rest of the list as you cannot see it.  Your Listbox Height is greater than your screen height.

Answer (score 3):

[`tkListAutoWidth.py`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207151435id_/http://svn.effbot.org/public/stuff/sandbox/tkinter/tkListAutoWidth.py) shows one way to do it.

Edit:

So you might have something along the lines of,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font


class NewListbox(tk.Listbox):

    def autowidth(self, maxwidth=100)
        autowidth(self, maxwidth)


def autowidth(list, maxwidth=100):
    f = font.Font(font=list.cget("font"))
    pixels = 0
    for item in list.get(0, "end"):
        pixels = max(pixels, f.measure(item))
    # bump listbox size until all entries fit
    pixels = pixels + 10
    width = int(list.cget("width"))
    for w in range(0, maxwidth+1, 5):
        if list.winfo_reqwidth() >= pixels:
            break
        list.config(width=width+w)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    master = tk.Tk()
    listbox = NewListbox(master, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)

    # ...
    # ...
    keys = serverDict.keys()
    for key in sorted(keys):
        listbox.insert("end", key)

    listbox.pack()

    button = tk.Button(master, text="Execute", command=execute)
    button.pack()

    listbox.autowidth()

    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: It might be easiest to put the class directly into your code. With one or two small changes, it should be fine on python 3.3. see my edit above.