# Make text in a tkinter Listbox fit inside?

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I've looked everywhere for a fix to this. I stumbled across this:

[How to fit Tkinter listbox to contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705745/how-to-fit-tkinter-listbox-to-contents)

But this question is asking the reverse of what I want. I want the box to remain the size I've set it to, but the text runs off of the side like in the screenshot from the above linked question. Is there anyway to force a `\n` to be added to the string once its character count reaches the length of the listbox?

Also, I apologize if something is wrong with the format of my question, I've never posted here before.

```
class Stars(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.feed = Listbox(self, width = 55 , height = 31, relief = SUNKEN, borderwidth = 3)
        self.feed.grid(row = 1, column = 2, columnspan = 2)

    def simulate(self):
        self.mass = eval(self.massEntry.get())
        self.feed.insert(END, 'Star to be created with mass of {} * 10^30 kg; {} solar masses.'.format(1.98855 * self.mass, self.mass))
        self.feed.insert(END, '0 years: Protostar formed in an interstellar gas cloud, and begins to compress due to gravity.')
```

This is all of the relevant code (trying to make a stellar evolution simulation). This is what it looks like when run, with the problem circled in red:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VjOM.jpg

Comment: Could you provide relevant,working code?

Comment: sorry, updated original post

Comment: your code isn't properly indented

Comment: That isn't how it is in my actual code, I just pasted it over here incorrectly, I didn't mean to include that `try`. Fixed.

Comment: Is there a good reason for using a `Listbox` and not just a `Text` widget for the activity feed? This would solve the wrapping problem, but would admittedly be useless if you need to be able to select activity items for some reason?

Comment: It appears that the answer to your question is no. This has been asked in various other places and the answer is always to move away from using listbox, or to create a custom widget (e.g. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/130487/tkinter-listbox-question).

Comment: ebarr, I have no idea what I was thinking, but that was the solution :P, There is no need to select the items in the feed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to have a `Listbox` wrap the text. If you want to support wrapping, use a `Text` widget. If you want to select items like in a listbox, you can add some custom bindings to do that.

Comment: I got it working with a text widget. Now the text will all fit, but words will be cut off, so half the word is on one line and half the word is on another. Is there a way to change the text alignment, I suppose it would be called, so if a whole word won't fit on the rest of the line it will go to the next?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `wrap` attribute? Set it to `"word"` to have it wrap at word boundaries. By default it wraps at character boundaries.