# Resizing tkinter listbox to width of largest item, using .grid

Tags: python, algorithm, tkinter, resize, widget

I have two listboxes that are side by side. They use the lstBox.grid() method to order them in the window. I then have a dropdown option that changes the items displayed in one of the listboxes. The ultimate aim here is to be able to "add" items from one box to the other, and remove ones from the other. My issue is that I don't know how to expand the list box width to be that of the largest item it contains. I have a method that is used for handling when the dropdown is changed, and determining its value to change the items as appropriate, but te listbox doesn't change width.

I am aware that by using `lstBox.pack(fill=X,expand=YES)`, the listbox will resize, but i'm using the `.grid()` geometry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705745/how-to-fit-tkinter-listbox-to-contents

Comment: @EricLevieil I saw this, however as stated in my question, i want to use the `.grid()`geometry rather than `.pack`, and the answers to the question you referenced uses `.pack()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all your items to find the biggest (if there aren't too much it should be fine). For instance with strings you count their length with 'len(item)'.
Then, when you create your listbox (not when you grid it) your set its width with 'width = "The size you want" ', if the size you put in there is well defined with regard to the length of the biggest item, you shouldn't have any problem.(I think I remember, the listbox's width's unity is given by the size of the text in it, but it needs to be checked)

I don't know grid that much, so that I don't know if there is any faster option to do it.

It should look something like this:

```
len_max = 0
list_items = ["item2", "item2", "item3+a few characters for the size"]
for m in list_items:
    if len(m) > len_max:
        len_max = len(m)

import tkinter
master = Tk()

my_listbox1 = Listbox(master, width = len_max)
my_listbox1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

my_listbox2 = Listbox(master, width = len_max)
my_listbox2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

my_listbox1.insert(END, list_items[0])
my_listbox2.insert(END, list_items[1])
my_listbox2.insert(END, list_items[2])

master.mainloop()
```