# tkinter, python: Button not showing up after Listbox, and Listbox not responding at all

Tags: python, tkinter, button, listbox

I'm a tkinter newb, making slow progress. This question is about my `parse_html` func but I included relevant `main` code too. I can't figure out why the `OK` button isn't even showing up after the Listbox. While I do have a correct list of options showing up in my Listbox, and `retval` prints out the correct value, I'm stuck at this point because nothing is happening in the `lbox` section, and the `ok_btn` button is missing. I'm not even sure if one is causing the other. 
Any help would truly be appreciated. Thank you!

Updates: Noticed the banner Label also disappears when the Listbox is put in. Added function `get_html_source_dirs` to code below, just in case it's part of the problem.

**Resolved:** Added a `max_len` of `choices` to use as width of Listbox per Answer below. My problem was a symptom of [Resizing tkinter listbox to width of largest item, using .grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046479/resizing-tkinter-listbox-to-width-of-largest-item-using-grid)

```
    choices = StringVar(value=get_html_source_dirs())
    max_len = max([len(c) for c in get_html_source_dirs()])
    lbox = Listbox(master=new, listvariable=choices, width=max_len+2, selectmode=SINGLE)
```

```
## `test_write` is a decorator, just substitute `print`. Sorry... 
def parse_html(win):

    def get_html_source_dirs():
        ''' CACHED_DIR and CACHE_ARCHIVES are WindowsPath type'''
        dirs = [CACHE_DIR.stem] 
        dirs.extend([name for name in os.listdir(CACHE_ARCHIVES) if (CACHE_ARCHIVES/name).is_dir()])
        return dirs

    def on_selection(event):
        retval = [lbox.get(index) for index in lbox.curselection()]
        # test_write(f"{retval}")
        ## ?? Assume I only need the one value for selectmode=SINGLE??
        return retval[0] 
  
    def click_ok(event):
        ''' Will launch the parser with the selected directory as the argument '''
        pass 

    new = Toplevel(win)
    new.geometry("450x300")
    new.title("Parse HTML")
    banner = Label(master=new, text="Select source directory and click OK")
    banner.grid(row=0, column=1)
    choices = StringVar(value=get_html_source_dirs()) ## There are fewer than 10 options
    lbox = Listbox(master=new, listvariable=choices, width=400, selectmode=SINGLE)
    lbox.grid(row=2, column=1)
    lbox.selection_set(0) # Default setting
    ## ?? Not sure if '<ButtonRelease>' or '<<ListboxSelection>>' is more correct??
    lbox.bind('<ButtonRelease>', on_selection)
    test_write(f"{lbox.get(lbox.curselection())}")

    ## ?? Not sure if I need this step??
    # lbox.insert(0, *get_html_files()) 

    ## ?? This print statement only shows the very first time, not even after lbox.bind
    # test_write(f"{lbox.index('active')}")    

    ok_btn = Button(master=new, text='OK')
    ok_btn.grid(row=3, column=1)
    ok_btn.configure(command=lambda: click_ok(win))

    new.mainloop()


def main():
    win = Tk()
    frame1 = Frame(win)
    frame1.pack(fill= BOTH, expand= True, padx= 10, pady=20)

    ... # other buttons

    PARSE_HTML = Label(frame1, text='Process saved files:', padx=10, pady=10)
    PARSE_HTML.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
    process_button = Button(frame1, text='PROCESS HTML', padx=10, pady=5)
    process_button.grid(row=3, column=1)
    process_button.configure(command=lambda: parse_html(win))

    ... # more buttons

    win.mainloop()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you maximized the screen to see if it shows up? Your window size may be too small to see it?

Comment: Good thought, but... The window looked big enough but checked JIC and that's not the problem. :`( If I comment out just the Listbox portion, the Button is back. I didn't see it before but the Row 0 Label also disappears with the Listbox.

Comment: Interesting... The texts do not display correctly with `grid`. But it works fine with `pack`. Try replacing `banner.grid(row=0, column=1)` with `banner.pack(side="top")` (same thing for `lbox` and `ok_btn`). Btw `test_write` is not defined in your example.

Comment: I don't think you understand Bryan's answer well.  Expanding the window size to "500x600" cannot show a label at around 1800 *horizontally* (i.e. x ~ 1800).  You need to change the width of the listbox to something like 40 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the listbox width to 400. That's 400 *characters*, not pixels. On my machine that makes it about 3600 pixels wide. Since you don't use any other options when calling `grid`, the label and button will be centered, meaning they will be roughly at pixel position 1800.

Change the width to something more sane and the label and button should appear.

```
lbox = Listbox(master=new, listvariable=choices, width=40, selectmode=SINGLE)
#                                                      ^^
```

Comment: See my above Update please. I added a screenshot. I fiddled around with sizes but it doesn't show up or react as you've described. Could it be the tkinter render colliding with my monitor settings?

Comment: @MeghanM. Just like this answer says, you are creating a **listbox** that is several thousand pixels wide. You need to set an order of magnitude smaller. It forces all other widgets outside the edges of the window.

Comment: @MeghanM. yes, that is correct.

Comment: OH!! So essentially, Listbox(width=) uses characters, but Tk.geometry() renders in pixels? OK made adjustments and that works! Sorry, it wasn't clear that was what you meant. Also, "Resizing tkinter listbox to width of largest item, using .grid", [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046479/resizing-tkinter-listbox-to-width-of-largest-item-using-grid] helps explain it further.