# I'm trying to print something letter by letter in a new window with tkinter import, but when I run it through the terminal the window doesn't pop up

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

import time

while True:

    for message in "Hello World":
        time.sleep(.5)

root = Tk()

lb = Listbox(root, height=3)

lb.pack()

lb.insert(END, message)

lb.insert(END,"second entry")

lb.insert(END,"third entry")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have to use `root.after` to call function repeatedly and this function has to add new text.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `root.after` to call function which add single letter, and then it use `root.after` to call the same function to add next letter.

```
from Tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def add_letter(text):
    if text: # if text not empty
        # add first letter from text
        lb.insert(END, text[0])
        # call again without first letter
        root.after(500, add_letter, text[1:])

# --- main ---

root = Tk()
lb = Listbox(root, height=15)
lb.pack()

# first call after 500ms 
root.after(500, add_letter, "Hello World")

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** moving text :) using `Text` and reversed text

```
from Tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def add_letter(text):
    if text: # if text not empty
        # add first letter from text
        lb.insert('1.0', text[0]) # put at the beginning of line
        # call again without first letter
        root.after(250, add_letter, text[1:])

# --- main ---

root = Tk()
lb = Text(root)
lb.pack()

text = ''.join(reversed("Hello World of Python and Tkinter"))
# first call after 250ms 
root.after(250, add_letter, text)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code never progresses beyond the `while True:` loop. So the rest of the code that creates the windows and widgets is not executed, hence no window appears.

Try removing the while loop:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

for message in "Hello World":
    time.sleep(.5)

root = Tk()
lb = Listbox(root, height=3)
lb.pack()
lb.insert(END, message)
lb.insert(END,"second entry")
lb.insert(END,"third entry")

root.mainloop()
```

Now your code will loop over the character in the string, sleeping 0.5 seconds for each character. Then the window and widgets will be created and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted would be stuck in an infinite loop (the while True) sleeping over and over for .5 seconds per character in "Hello World"

The first issue is the While and sleep, both of which are unnecessary. If you want the letters, you're on the right track, since string are lists of char in Python

I believe you want something like the following:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
lb = Tkinter.Listbox(root, height=3)
lb.pack()
for message in "Hello World":
    lb.insert(Tkinter.END, message)

lb.insert(Tkinter.END, "second last entry")
lb.insert(Tkinter.END, "THE last entry")
lb.config(height=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Notice the config resize, since otherwise we can only see the elements beyond H e l if we click into the list and scroll using arrow keys. The following could help you understand how to get the listbox to resize :)

[How to fit Tkinter listbox to contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705745/how-to-fit-tkinter-listbox-to-contents)